# How to COUNT values and and use it as a variable in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Basically,  What i am trying to do is ;

The number of classes required is a variable. EG. The user could put 5 , 4  as a minimum.

Since i am new, i cant upload pictures, But here is a picture of my ER diagram, to get a idea of the table structures.

I am using sql server 2005

Comment: What did you already try to do ? What problem did you meet ?

Comment: I dont know how to construct the sql code

Comment: You say you're using "Oracle, SQL Server 2005" - which is it? This smells like homework to me.

Comment: SQL stored procs without variables will be of very few use. Have a look at : http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7131.asp

Answer (score 0):

First off your question is poorly phrased; it is difficult to get a sense of what it is you are trying to achieve.

To get the number of rows from a dataset which meet the required condition, then use SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Tablename Where WhereCondition.

I can't see your ER diagram so I'll hypothesise; this should return attendance by class.

```
DECLARE @Students TABLE (id int, StudentName nvarchar(max));
DECLARE @Classes TABLE (id int, ClassName nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @StudentClassAttendance TABLE (ClassAttendanceID int, StudentId int, ClassId int, StartTime datetime)

SELECT sca.StudentID, s.StudentName, COUNT(sca.ClassAttendanceID), c.ClassName
FROM 
@Students s
INNER JOIN @StudentClassAttendance sca
ON sca.StudentId = s.Id
INNER JOIN @Classes c
ON c.Id = sca.ClassId
GROUP BY 
sca.StudentID, s.StudentName, ClassName
```